# SQLite C++ API Transactions slow

Tags: c++, database, performance, sqlite, transactions

I have a problem with SQLite. It seems that every call takes ~300ms to execute. After some testing I noticed that the delay is caused by transactions. 8 normal inserts with implicit transactions take about 2 seconds, however, if I start a transaction before the inserts and commit it after, I can do almost a million inserts in the same time. Calls affected include DROP TABLE, CREATE TABLE, INSERT and I assume others, too (probably all that implicitly begin a transaction).

Some more info:

- Downloaded the source amalgamation from the SQLite website (3200100)
- Compiled it using Visual Studio into a static library (Not using any compiler flags, although I have been playing around with them without luck)
- I am using sqlite3_open16 followed by sqlite3_prepare16_v3 and then sqlite3_step to start execution and/or receive the first result
- No multithreading, no access from multiple processes, database file is exclusively opened by this program
- If I create the file on my SSD (960 EVO) instead the "transaction delay" goes from 300ms down to 10ms. Still an absurdly high value, though, but I feel like the speed of my disk shouldn't influence whatever is slowing the transactions down?
- The function that is blocking is sqlite3_step (It also annoys me that I have to call a function with that name just to execute a DROP TABLE, for example, but not that it matters)
- Edit: During the transaction, the CPU usage is 100%.

On a side note, is it possible to "help" SQLite with organizing data if you know that every single row of your table will be exactly, say, 64 Byte?

I hope you can help me with this or possibly recommend an alternative (relational, c++ api, file based, highly performant)
Thank you very much!

Comment: DROP and CREATE TABLE can be very expensive as it is unusual to perform these two commands unless creating a new database or making complicated upgrades to an existing database schema.  DROP/CREATE also have to make extensive changes/checks to the database meta-data (the schema).  INSERT should be fast unless you have many indexes / foreign-keys on the table.

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19). Consider using [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), which writes asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite makes lots of effort to ensure it doesn't suffer data corruption, so with an implicit transaction, you are limited by your hard disk speed.

With a transaction, the data is written to other locations, and only committed to disk once, and is much faster

From [sqlite speed](https://sqlite.org/speed.html)

> With synchronization turned on, SQLite executes an fsync() system call (or the equivalent) at key points to make certain that critical data has actually been written to the disk drive surface.

When creating a transaction, the data is written to other files, and only when all the data is committed, will the fsync cost be paid, and all together.  That is a price for that part of the configuration.  A positive from this, is I have never suffered from sqlite data loss through corruption.

> I feel like the speed of my disk shouldn't influence whatever is slowing the transactions down?

This is an important trade-off.  If you want improved data integrity, then the speed of your disk is relevant.

> How long does committing a transaction take?

From [sqlite faq :19 why are transactions slow](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q19)

> SQLite will easily do 50,000 or more INSERT statements per second on an average desktop computer. But it will only do a few dozen transactions per second.

You can :-

1. Use transactions to bind more work.  The cost is per transaction, so can be bulked up.
2. Use temporary tables.  Temporary tables do not suffer the performance, and will run at full speed.
3. NOT RECOMMENDED.  Use  `PRAGMA synchronous=OFF` to disable the synchronous write.

Comment: Setting the journalling mode to WAL was indeed what I wanted (from a consistency standpoint and a performance standpoint). The values now make a lot more sense with 32 transactions per second on a normal hard disk and over 512 on the SSD. Thanks very much, I can't believe I missed that info in the FAQ!